# Qt cant join multicast group of the specified networkInterface

Tags: qt, multicast, qudpsocket

I use QT5.6.3 on MACOS10.15.
I have two ethernet interface. One is en0 , another one is en6. the en0's IP is 192.168.10.199, the en6'IP is 192.168.1.123.
Now I need to receive multicast from en0 .the multicast group address 239.255.255.251 , the multicast port is 47810.
   Here is my simplified code:

```
   groupAddress = QHostAddress("239.255.255.251");
   QNetworkInterface _interface = QNetworkInterface::interfaceFromName("en6");
   udpSocket = new QUdpSocket(this);
   udpSocket->bind(QHostAddress::AnyIPv4, 47810, QUdpSocket::ShareAddress|QUdpSocket::ReuseAddressHint );
   //I am sure the _interface is en6
   udpSocket->setMulticastInterface(_interface);
   udpSocket->joinMulticastGroup(groupAddress,_interface));
```

But, I use netstat command , I find the en0 join the multicast group, not my designated en6

```
IPv4 Multicast Group Memberships
Group                   Link-layer Address  Netif
224.0.0.251             <none>              lo0
224.0.0.1               <none>              lo0
**239.255.255.251       1:0:5e:7f:ff:fb     en0**
224.0.0.1               1:0:5e:0:0:1        en0
224.0.0.251             1:0:5e:0:0:fb       en0
224.0.0.251             1:0:5e:0:0:fb       en6
224.0.0.1               1:0:5e:0:0:1        en6
```

How can I let en6 join the multicast group .It like joinMulticastGroup by interface don't work .
Please help me ,thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's Qt5.6.3's bug.
This bug is fixed in 5.11 or later.